# Add a !NEW! marker in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to add a label / property / anything to a title so that in the contents page it will show up with a symbol / the word NEW / highlighting somewhere, so it's obvious?

A little asterisk to the left of the section number or something?

Essentially i'm writing a library, and documenting it as i go, and distributing it regularly. I'd like to be able to add flags to the titles (or even better a "date added" field, and then have the contents generate the symbols automatically for anything after a provided date) so that people getting the new documentation can quickly see the new additions.

Sure i could have a "new" section at the beginning and put links in there, but i'd quite like to have the new entries added in the contents page.

example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=DodgerBlue4,
    filecolor=Firebrick4,
    linkcolor=Cyan4,
    urlcolor=DeepSkyBlue1
}

\title{title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\section{sec1}
\subsection{subsec11}
\subsection{subsec12}
\subsection{subsec13} % i want to make this section display some sort of symbol in the contents.
\subsection{subsec14}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please add a minimal example of your code we need to know the class packages (related to toc) do you use.

Comment: @touhami there you go.

Answer (score 2):

A trick is by redefining `\numberline` command or similar.
One add `\mtnew`  befor each  new section

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mtnew{%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\let\protect\oldnumberline\protect\numberline%
\def\protect\numberline{%
\global\let\protect\numberline\protect\oldnumberline
\protect\llap{*New* }\protect\oldnumberline}}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\subsection{Foo}
\mtnew
\subsection{Bar}
\section{Second}
\mtnew
\section{New section}
\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

**Update** Here is a solution that fill your need. A new command `\newsec` is defined to be used

```
\newsec[level]{heading}
```

level is `section`(default) `subsection` ....

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=15mm, right=15mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=DodgerBlue4,
    filecolor=Firebrick4,
    linkcolor=Cyan4,
    urlcolor=DeepSkyBlue1
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsec}[2][section]{%
\def\@seccntformat##1{\protect\llap{\normalfont\normalsize*New* }\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\let\protect\mtnumberline\protect\numberline%
\def\protect\numberline{%
\hskip-\parindent%
\global\let\protect\numberline\protect\mtnumberline%
\protect\llap{\normalfont\normalsize*New* }%
\hskip\parindent\protect\mtnumberline}}%
\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
\def\@seccntformat##1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\section{sec1}
\subsection{subsec11}
\subsection{subsec12}
\newsec{sec2}                   % here new section
\subsection{subsec21}
\section{sec3}
\newsec[subsection]{subsec31}   % here new subsection
\subsection{subsec32}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nearly works - i don't get it showing in front of the section heading, only in the contents.

Comment: you want the (new) symbol even in the body at left of section heading, this is?

Comment: in your example the symbol shows in the margin next to the section headings. for me it does not. Though just being in the contents is good enough for my purposes.

Comment: it's not clear for me where do you want the symbol: at left of the number? after the number at left of the headinf?

Comment: there are two things. Firstly, i would like to see it next to the section heading, as well as in the contents. It is in both in your example, but for some reason it's not for me. I need to work out why - that is my problem though. Secondly, could you make it sit in the margin, rather than to the left of the item? so that it is always in the same place?